# How to make hacked files in Subversion repository editable again?

Tags: files, subversion, version-control

I'm investigating some files in a website which were hacked and the site is under version control in a Subversion repository, but it doesn't show the files as being modified. How do I stop SVN from ignoring the files so I can check in clean copies?

I'm cleaning up a website that was hacked (relatively minor, some casino links were added to a page header) and the site is hosted from a working copy of an SVN repo. (Yes, it does have a functioning .htaccess file that prevents access to the `.svn` folders.) Interestingly, the hacked file has the modification date of the last updated version in the SVN repo, `svn status` shows it as being unmodified, `svn log -v <hacked_file>` shows no commits past the last updated version in the SVN repo, `svn diff <hacked_file>` also shows no difference between the file and the last modified version in the repo. I whipped up some scripts to check logs & diffs between each version and there's nothing modifying that file.

However, I noticed that the file name does appear in `.svn/all-wcprops`, as follows:

```
K 25
svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url
V 48
/<repo>/!svn/ver/97/trunk/www.example.com/<hacked_file>
END
favicon.ico
```

Naturally, `svn proplist -v <hacked_file>` doesn't output anything and `svn propget 'svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url' <hacked_file>` returns an error saying it's "a wcprop, thus not accessible to clients".

I'm not seeing any 'svn:ignore' props and `svn status --no-ignore` doesn't show the hacked file.

I've done a lot of research and am really not finding any information in SVN 'wcprops' or `.svn/all-wcprops`. Is it safe to delete the `all-wcprops` file?

Any other possibilities/options/advice other than blowing away the working copy and checking on a fresh copy (this in an all-too-large repo, so it's time consuming and would take a long time to review to make sure everything is working, esp. since I can't trust that there are no modified files that might be lost)? Is this something that was likely modified in the main SVN repo?

Comment: Blowing it away and restoring from a known-good version is the right thing to do regardless. As you say, you can't trust that there are no modified files that might *not* be lost...

Comment: @MichaelHomer Err, restore it to the version that was just cracked a few hours ago? :)

Comment: Over leaving up the version that is known to be compromised right now and can never be trusted again? Yes. Blow the whole account away, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it's best to check out a fresh copy of the repository from SVN anyway, since the working copy is both untrustworthy and unreliable. So, I did the following:

- Checked out a new working copy
- Confirmed that the contents of the hacked file were correct as appeared in the repository, without the malicious modifications
- Confirmed that modifications to the hacked file (and others listed in `.svn/all-wcprops`) would show as modified by `svn status` when edited
- Swapped out the working copies
- Ran `diff -qrx .svn <hacked_working_copy>/ <new_working_copy>/` to determine what files were actually changed/added in the hacked working copy, but not showing as such
- Confirmed the contents of, and manually copied over, any uncommitted files, as necessary
- Archived & removed the hacked working copy for further investigation/evidence, then removed it

Naturally, further action & precautions are being taken, but the recursive `diff` made it easy to identify questionable files.